# what's the advantage of java security framework?

Tags: spring-security, shiro

Compare to save user identity to session and use interceptor to authorize.

Like:

#### authentication：

```
@RequestMapping("/checkLogin.do")
public String checkLogin(Map map, HttpSession httpSession, String username, String password) {

    JSONObject userJson = userService.checkLogin(username, password);

    if ((Integer) userJson.get("success") == 0) {
        httpSession.setAttribute("userinfo", userJson);
        return "redirect:/index.do";
    } else {
        map.put("error", -1);
        return "login";
}
```

#### authorization：

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2) throws Exception {
        String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String userinfo= (String) session.getAttribute("userinfo");
        if (userinfo!= null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            arg1.sendRedirect("/login.do");
            return false;
        }

}
```

what's the benefit using security framework such as shiro or spring-security?

Answer (score 0):

In short, the benefit comes in how fast you can incorporate security related requirements into your project; Basic security requirements might be permissions management and role based authorization while more complex requirements might be cross platform session management.